# Cross platform crash-reporters

Tags: c++, crash, cross-platform, crash-dumps, diagnostics

Are there any cross platform crash reporters for C++ besides google-break pad? I have seen google-breakpad but it has very very limited documentation, and I have nothing seen very much mentioned here, google or other source websites

Comment: I thought of the Mozilla crash reporter, but it looks like they use breakpadniw too. They might have some good docs to check out, though.

Comment: They do not, do you happen to have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [BugTrap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14618/Catch-All-Bugs-with-BugTrap) which might help you.

Comment: Sadly it looks like BugTrap is only Windows based (also from quick looking at source code I see .cs files so I'm not sure if it's even cpp meaning it's far than being portable of cross-platform...)